# BaseX: Query request error : Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: xml, database, basex

I have installed a BaseX server to allow creation of database on my computer.
I have the following XML database managed by BaseX  :

```
<config>
  <datas>
    <datas_types>
      <data_type id="1" name="data1"/>
      <data_type id="2" name="data2"/>
      <data_type id="3" name="data3"/>
    </data_types>
    <data_owner id="10" name="FirstOwner" description="FirstOwner description">
     <owner_info nat="nationality1" date="2020" role="role1"/>
    </data_owner>
  </datas>
</config>
```

Now, I would like to return information from my database thanks to query requests called with URL.
To access my database, my URL is : http://localhostadress:port/rest/database_name

Then, I tried to use query functions such as number() or string() for example to get the id of a specified owner or the name of it as follows :

```
http://localhostadress:port/rest/database_name?query=number(/config/datas/data_owner[@name="FirstOwner"]/@id)

http://localhostadress:port/rest/database_name?query=string(/config/datas/data_owner[@id=10]/@name)
```

It is actuallly working when I use these requests in the BaseX software but if I use the same query requests directly in my URL adress, the following errror appears :

```
error on line 1 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
```

I don't know what I do wrong ?
Could anyone help me please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where does the error appear? In the browser? Can you look with F12 in the browser's developer console and check the actual HTTP request and response data exchanged by the browser and the BaseX server and show us that data?

Comment: Does appending `http://localhostadress:port/rest/database_name?query=number(/config/datas/data_owner[@name="FirstOwner"]/@id)&method=text` help?